# Unity Firebase missing sdk

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

So, I've been trying to get the Firebase working with Unity. I'm very excited about it!...or I would be if I could figure it out what I'm doing wrong...I'm sure it's something completely obvious.

The short and sweet version of my problem:
  I was eventually able to set up the pre-made unity project that google provides for you. I got the firebase sdk imported along with the json file I need to have. it works great! I can see the accounts that I'm creating with it in the firebase console. The problem I'm having is when I set up a new Unity Project, import all of the sdks,import the  json file,  and switch the platform to android, it gives me an error that says I'm missing these sdk packages:
                              *extras;google;m2repository
                              *extras;android;m2repository
    It then asks me if I'd like to wait while I install them, I say yes, but it never seems to fix the issue....and the builds never work.

What is missing in my empty Unity project that isn't in the pre-made Unity project supplied by google? I MUST have those "missing" sdks if the other project can find them with no errors, right?

I'm happy to provide as many details as you might need, and I really REALLY appreciate any help (in addition to the help that this site has provided so far!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Google Play services installed? You can get them from the SDK Manager in Android Studio

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback! I do have Google Play Services imstalled. Its really odd. I can open the example Unity projects that the Firebase website gives you to try things out, and they work. I can open them up, and erase everything in them, then make my own project, and it works just fine with no errors. I'm guess theres something the editor Im not clicking, and I just cant figure it out!